# Vue mapbox print the map

Tags: jquery, vue.js, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

i have trouble while am printing a map in my vue page.i have a chart and marker on the map and the problem comes here when i print the page the background of the marker and chart become white i tried many ways like by by making the background transparent
`@media print{
background-color: transparent !important;
}`
[image: even the mapbox log background is white]

even the mapbox logo background is white too..

anybody help ..thanks

Comment: You should include information like which browser this happens on, what method you're using to print, etc.

Comment: am using chrome and i simply use command + p to print